# JavaScript window.getComputedStyle

Tags: javascript

How can I get windows.getComputed style as an int value?

The way it is displayed by default is string:

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle(elem1, null);
alert(style.top); //Returns a string
```

Comment: Note that `style.top` could return a non-numeric value like `"auto"`. (By the way, what happened when you typed "javascript convert string to int" into Google?)

Comment: no, i could have used substr or something. i just thought i could use some easier way.

Answer (score 1):

`parseInt()` will return you the String as an Integer, so your code should look somehow like this:

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle(elem1, null);
alert(parseInt(style.top));
```

Answer (score 1):

`parseFloat` will give you the real value as a number with decimal places preserved:

```
parseFloat(style.top);
```